# Push multiple UICollectionViewCell to the same UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` with multiple `UICollectionViewCell` when I clicked to any cell it's supposed to push me to another UIViewController with UITableView.

All I want is every UICollectionViewCell to call a specific API based on indexPath and put the response in UITableView.

Example:

If I clicked on the "Beef" cell the API will like that "https://apilink.com/recipes/random?search=beef", and so on with the other cells.

I'm not using storyboard at all, I'm using the programmatically approach.

**HomeView:**

```
protocol HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath)
}


class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    weak var homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .customDarkGray(), indicatorColor: .white)
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fetchData()
        }

    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("https://api.com").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                if let data = response.data {
                    self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: data)
                    self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView(self)
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return recipesDetails.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.recipesDidselectActionDelegate = self
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
            let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
            cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title

            if let readyInMin = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].readyInMinutes {
                cell.cookingTimeInfoLabel.text = "\(readyInMin) Minutes"
            }

            if let pricePerServing = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].pricePerServing {
                cell.priceInfoLabel.text = "$\(Int(pricePerServing))"
            }

            if let serving = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].servings {
                cell.servesInfoLabel.text = "\(serving)"
            }

            return cell
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 2 {
            return "Random recipes"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = .customDarkGray()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 130
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return 180
        } else {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }

    }

}

extension HomeView: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
            homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**HomeViewController:**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuTableViewController())

    lazy var mainView: HomeView = {
        let view = HomeView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate = self
        return view
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = mainView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        .lightContent
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        setupNavigationWithLargeTitle()
        setupLeftSideMenu()
        setupNavigation()
    }

    func setupLeftSideMenu() {
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
        leftMenuNavigationController.leftSide = true
        leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        leftMenuNavigationController.presentationStyle = .viewSlideOut
        leftMenuNavigationController.allowPushOfSameClassTwice = false
        leftMenuNavigationController.menuWidth = view.frame.width * (3/4)
        leftMenuNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func setupNavigationWithLargeTitle() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.title = "Home"
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen()]
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen(), .font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: 36)!]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
    }

    @objc func saveButtonTapped() {
        print("OK")
    }

    @objc func menuButtonTapped() {
        self.present(leftMenuNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Here you can push your destination View Controller
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
            self.show(vc, sender: nil)
        }

    }
}
```

**CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell:**

```
protocol RecipesDidselectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    weak var recipesDidselectActionDelegate: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate?

    let categories: [String] = [
        "Main course",
        "Beef",
        "Chicken",
        "Seafood",
        "Vegetarian",
        "Breakfast",
        "Side dish",
        "Drink",
        "Sauce",
        "Soup",
        "Snacks",
        "Dessert"
    ]

    let categoriesImages: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "maincourse")!,
        UIImage(named: "beef")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "seafood")!,
        UIImage(named: "vegetarian")!,
        UIImage(named: "breakfast")!,
        UIImage(named: "sidedish")!,
        UIImage(named: "drink")!,
        UIImage(named: "sauce")!,
        UIImage(named: "soup")!,
        UIImage(named: "snacks")!,
        UIImage(named: "dessert")!
    ]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            seeAllCategoriesButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}


extension CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell
        cell.categoriesImage.image = categoriesImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryName.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        recipesDidselectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let w: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 0.4
        let h: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.height - 6.0
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }

}
```

**RecipesTableViewDetailsView:**

```
class RecipesTableViewDetailsView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
//        fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .customDarkGray(), indicatorColor: .white)
        AF.request("https://api.com").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                if let data = response.data {
                    self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: data)
                    self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView(self)
        }
    }

}

extension RecipesTableViewDetailsView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipesDetails.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
        cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title

        if let readyInMin = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].readyInMinutes {
            cell.cookingTimeInfoLabel.text = "\(readyInMin) Minutes"
        }

        if let pricePerServing = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].pricePerServing {
            cell.priceInfoLabel.text = "$\(Int(pricePerServing))"
        }

        if let serving = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].servings {
            cell.servesInfoLabel.text = "\(serving)"
        }

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

}
```

Comment: is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: @kjoe Every cell has its own API that it must fetch when I clicked it and the result will be put in UITableView, what I want is how to make it

Comment: When you say *what I want is how to make it*, what is the *it*? Step back, forget for a moment what you know, and try to read this question from the point of view of someone who has no idea what problem you're having. Can you point to the part where you say specifically what the problem is?

Comment: You have code but question is unclear what you want? When you tap the collectionView send the tapped object ID/model object to detail view and it will download required data

Comment: @Caleb Sorry if my question not clear enough, I want every UICollectionViewCell to call a specific API based on indexPath and put the response in UITableView. I don't know if this cleared enough or not, please tell me

Comment: @nkp Yes I want every cell to a specific API and put the response in UITableView

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the **categories** array item index to **UICollectionViewCell**.

then you can create dynamic API using cell.tag in `didSelectItemAt` function

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let id = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.tag
        let link = "https://apilink.com/recipes/random?search=\(categories[id])"
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I don't think it's gonna work with me because I'm using a different approach (protocol method).